# jQuery: Navigate based on <Option> Selected

Tags: jquery

Newbie  Question:

In jQuery how would I make the browser navigate to the selected drink when selected?

```
<select name="selDrink" id="selDrink">
    <option value="http://coke.com">Coke</option>
    <option value="http://pepsi.com">Pepsi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//select the element and bind a `change` event handler to it
$('#selDrink').on('change', function () {

    //redirect the user to the value of the select element
    window.location = this.value;
});
```

You will probably want to have a blank `<option>` at the top so all the `<option>`s with actual `value`s will be selectable:

HTML --

```
<select name="selDrink" id="selDrink">
    <option value="">Choose One</option>
    <option value="http://coke.com">Coke</option>
    <option value="http://pepsi.com">Pepsi</option>
</select>
```

JS --

```
$('#selDrink').on('change', function () {

    //check if the selected value of this element is blank, if not then redirect to the value
    if (this.value != '') {
        window.location = this.value;
    }
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is being used like `.bind()`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Duanx/

Docs for `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: Why do you use `on('change...` rather than just `change()`?

Comment: I like the syntax more, especially since to remove the event handler you use `.off()`. Another reason I like the syntax more is because of the ambiguity between `.change(function () {})` and `.change()`. I also use `.trigger('click')` instead of `.click()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selDrink").change(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="selDrink" id="selDrink">
    <option>Select a Drink</option>
    <option value="http://coke.com">Coke</option>
    <option value="http://pepsi.com">Pepsi</option>
</select>

<script>

   $( '#selDrink' ).change( function navigate() {

        window.location.href = $( this ).val();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#selDrink').change(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    });
});
```